# Why is this python loop not working as I expect?

Tags: python

Why does it not generate two random numbers untill theyre are 5 and 3?

```
import random

rolla = int(0)
rollb = int(0)


while rolla != 5 and rollb != 3:
  rolla = random.randint(1, 10)
  rollb = random.randint(1, 11)
  print(rolla, ' - ', rollb)
```

Comment: shorter: `rolla = 0` - it also assign integer zero to variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

rolla = 0
rollb = 0

while not(rolla == 5 and rollb == 3):
  rolla = random.randint(1, 10)
  rollb = random.randint(1, 11)
  print(rolla, ' - ', rollb)
```

you would have to use a not statement to encompass the entire phrase, otherwise it will stop if one of the conditions is false.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
while not (rolla == 5 and rollb == 3):
```